# Macports local cache area

Tags: macports

In what directory(local cache) of snow leopard does macports fetch and stores the packages downloaded using macports?

Answer (score 2):

Found out, this is the directory in which local copy of macports are stored **/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/**